# RGB LED Commond Anode Configuration

Tags: led-driver, rgb

I am trying to create a schematic for driving two [WP154A4SUREQBFZGC RGB LED diodes](http://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP154A4SUREQBFZGC.pdf) using [ON Semiconductor's CAT3626](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT3626-D.PDF) and here is my schematic:
[image: RGB LED Driving Schematic] and here is proposed circuit from `CAT3626's` datasheet:
[image: Proposed Circuit]
`Kingbright's RGB LED` [Altium's](https://www.altium.com/) part library was downloaded from [SamacSys webpage](https://componentsearchengine.com/ga/search.html?searchString=WP154A4SUREQBFZGC&country=GB&language=en&source=63). Now, I am confused since I've connected `anodes` to [PWM outputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) of `CAT3626` because I want to control every color of each diode indepedently, but in datasheet there is a connection as we can see from 2nd image **Common Anode Configuration**. How do I *transform* my schematic so it will comply with `CAT3626` "rules"?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics). Spend some time on it and it will benefit you greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the common anode [WP154A4SEJ3VBDZGW/CA](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Kingbright%20PDFs/WP154A4SEJ3VBDZGW-CA_Ver.1A_Jul-24-13.pdf) 
You selected the common cathode.

[image]

Comment: So, I selected wrong RGB LED itself, am I right? And I need to upgrade schematics with voltage divider for red channel, becuase it needs 2.2 (max 2.8) V?

Comment: Yes, you selected the wrong LED.  You should not need to treat the red any differently.  Each output channel (A,B, and C) the current is programed individually.   It's a current regulator so as long as Vout is sufficient (greater than max Vf) for all three channels the forward voltage does not matter.